# In R sub() function how to get a single backslach in "replacement"

Tags: r

In the R `sub()` I would like the output for the replacement to contain a single backslash, e.g. `\x`, but am having trouble generating this output. My first guess was this, but it doesn't return any backslashes

```
sub("xxx","\\x","xxx")
## [1] "x"
```

R does turn 4 escaped backslashes into two backslashes

```
sub("xxx","\\\\x","xxx")
## [1] "\\x"
```

This behavior also seems to persist in the `stringr` package

```
stringr::str_replace("xxx","xxx","\\x")
## [1] "x"
```

Comment: One backslash is for the escape.  You can check with `cat` i.e. `cat(sub("xxx","\\\\x","xxx"))#
\x`

Comment: Yeah, This is right. Thanks. I got tripped up and didn't combine it with `cat()`

Comment: Feel free to pass post that answer and I will gladly accept.